# How to handle.NET user setting path changes with assembly info changes?

Tags: c#, .net

I've noticed that when changes are made to the assemblyinfo.cs the hash that is used to generate the user settings path is changed.

The screen grab shows the two directories that were created when I changed the copyright date from 2014 to 2015.

[image]

I don't imagine I will change other items in the assemblyinfo, but I'm pretty sure I will change the copyright if I do another release next year.

What's the best way to handle this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The ApplicationSettings class has an [Upgrade](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.upgrade.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method which will move the existing setting values to the new settings file.

What I have done previously is to have a boolean flag as a setting (named something like UpgradeRequired) which indicates if an upgrade to the settings is required. This is set to true as default.

When the application starts, check this flag and call the `Upgrade()` method if required (and then set the UpgradeRequired setting to false).

```
if (Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired)
{
    Settings.Default.Upgrade();
    Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired = false;
    Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Comment: I am using Upgrade just as you described. However upgrade only (it seems) looks in the same application directory for different versions to migrate. What I am talking about is the fact that a relatively small change (ie copyright date) generates a completely new application directory that the Upgrade method doesn't search.